# Android DatePicker: How to reset DatePicker to current date automatically after the user selects the date?

Tags: android, datepicker, reset

Hello StackOverFlow Community,

I have created an app with two DatePickers in one activity. I need for the DatePicker to reset to the current date after the user chooses the date with it. Next, I have a clear button in the activity. I need that to also reset the DatePicker to the current date onClick of that button. Can anyone help me to accomplish this?

I really appreciate your time. Please, if you are going to give me a minus point for this question, can you explain why? I am trying to get better and that is why I am here. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void onResetClick(){
     resetDateToToday();
}

public void onDateSelected(){
     resetDateToToday();
}

public void resetDateToToday(){
     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
     datePicker.updateDate(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 1,cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Rajan, I when I try that I get the error message, "cannot resolve method updateDate". Any idea why?

Comment: That method is for datepicker , not on date picker dialog, you need to create datepicker and add it to datepicker dialog

Comment: private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener BirthDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
            year = selectedYear;
            month = selectedMonth;
            day = selectedDay;

            birthDate = new Date(year - 1900, month, day);
            formatedDate = sdf.format(birthDate);
            tv_birthDate.setText(formatedDate);



        }



    };

Comment: Sorry I tried to paste my datepicker section. It all came out paragraph form in the comment reply. Is that what you mean when you say create datepicker then add it to dialog? In other words, do I add it there? Sorry I just need some clarification. I already have the date pickers created and everything works fine aside from trying to clear them. I just need to know where to add it so I can make sure it works for me.